# Динамическое добавление объекта во время анимации

Tags: webgl, three.js, javascript

Сцена создана, запущена анимация.
По нажатию клавиши в сцену добавляется относительно "объемный" объект, иногда даже не один.
И в этот момент анимация зависает на время добавления объекта, что очень раздражает при анимации.
Как облегчить данную операцию? 
Например, при добавлении меша с THREE.PlaneGeometry(32,32,256,256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mrdoob дал ответ на GitHub.

Правильным решением оказалась замена геометрии на `BufferGeometry`, естественно, с последующими преобразованиями в `Plane`.